# Is there any way I can mark answers/comments as read, so when I revisit a question later I can go straight to the new stuff?

Tags: feature-request

Sorry if this idea has been floated before, but let's say I see a question that I am interested in, and it has a couple of answers/comments.

I go back later on and there is more answers and comments, currently I have to re-read the content from earlier before I get to the new stuff.

How about a checkbox on answers/comments that I can tick, so say that I have read them. When I go back later, new content and content that I marked earlier on as read that has been updated would take precedence over the content I read earlier that hasn't changed.

I had a look at the user scripts but couldn't see one for this, if one exists and somebody could point me towards it that would be great also!

Comment: For comments you can upvote the last one you read. You can do the same  for answers, but the order can change later.

Comment: Well for answers you could just change the sort order

Comment: For comments, no. For answers, you can order answers using `oldest` tab. It will order them by date. Also you can order them with `activity` which will consider latest activity on that answer (edits, new comments are all counted as activities on answers.)

Comment: @user000001 he should use upvoting only when he sees that they are helpful.  In addition, that won't work: what if the comment/answer was deleted?